# Detect Cycle in an undirected graph using Breadth First Search Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

> Using this algorithm I am getting wrong answers but my testcases are
> giving correct answers. Let me know where I am going wrong. In this
> algorithm I have used Breadth First Search(BFS) technique to find to
> detect the cycle.

```
// Using bfs approach
class Solution{
    public boolean isCycle(int V, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adj){
        Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<>();
        boolean vis[]=new boolean[V];
        int parent[]=new int[V];
        parent[0]=-1;
        q.add(0);
        vis[0]=true;
        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            int cur=q.poll();
            for(int  i:adj.get(cur)){
                // if(vis[i]==true) return true;
                if(!vis[i]){
                    q.add(i);
                    parent[i]=cur;
                    vis[i]=true;
                }
                else if(parent[cur]!=i) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "wrong" with your answer?

Comment: `for (int i : adj.get(cur))` is fishy. You are expecting `i` to be a vertex(index) in `vis[i]` but you are actually getting `i` as edge weight. You can correct it by using the classic `for` statement instead of the enhanced `for` statement. There are obviously other problems like `if(vis[i]) // break and return`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, can you please elaborate on 1. `for` statement and, and 2. `if (vis[i])`. Assuming the unweighed undirected graph is represented as adjacency list of vertices, then the `for` loop is correctly fetching the adjacent vertices. Further this code will work for connected graph. Additional calls to the method is needed for different forests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assumptions

The approach assumes that the input undirected graph is connected.

Please check whether it is a valid assumption for all possible inputs for the problem domain.

### Possible solution

1. The existing method will work for a single forest
2. Add additional `startNode` and  `visited` parameters to the existing method
3. Add another wrapper method that will call the existing method for every unvisited node(forest).

```java
  boolean hasCycle(final int N, final List<List<Integer>> graph) {
    final boolean[] visited = boolean[N];

    for (int vertex = 0; vertex < N; vertex++) {
      if (!visited[vertex] && hasCycle(N, vertex, visited, graph)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

### Both Methods

```java
  boolean hasCycle(final int N, final int start, final boolean[] visited, final List<List<Integer>> graph) {
    visited[start] = true;

    final int parent[] = new int[N];
    parent[start] = -1;

    final Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(start);

    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
      final int node = q.poll();

      // assumes for nodes without edges, an empty list will be returned
      for(int adj : graph.get(node)) {
        if (!visited[adj]) {
          q.add(adj);
          parent[adj] = node;
          visited[adj] = true;
        } else if (parent[node] != adj) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  boolean hasCycle(final int N, final List<List<Integer>> graph) {
    final boolean[] visited = boolean[N];

    for (int vertex = 0; vertex < N; vertex++) {
      if (!visited[vertex] && hasCycle(N, vertex, visited, graph)) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

### Disclaimer

This is untested and uncompiled code (typed in SO)